# How to programatically send data over bluetooth from windows 7 laptop?

Tags: windows, terminal, bluetooth

I am working a project from my school. We are using a microcontroller to send integers over bluetooth (Sparkfun's bluesmirf) to an android device.
Because different people need the microcontroller I am wondering if it is possible to programmatically send send data over bluetooth to my android phone via my laptop's bluetooth?

I previously was testing we CoolTerm, but I am only able to send data manually by pressing the Enter key each time.

I want to create a loop that sends a random number (12 digit long) over and over (differnet int each time) from my HP Pavilion DV7 laptop? I am using Windows 7 Ultimate, and Coolterm 1.4.1.

Comment: Now that you have mentioned `programatically` , which programming language you would use?

Comment: Hi, I am not sure which one. I know how to program C# and C++. I can use Dev-Cpp, Code Composer Studio, or Visual Studio. I looked into the suggessted 32feet .NET package, but I am not familair with .NET and I am unsure how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to this problem was using **[RealTerm](http://realterm.sourceforge.net/index.html#downloads_Download)**. 
I creared a *.txt file with the ints in each line (copy+paste from Excel table - made it easier). Then, after I connect to the Laptop's bluetooth port under the **Port** tab, I go to the **Send** tab and use the **Dump File To Port** option and add the *.txt file I created. Also, I used 999 as delay to send each line every 999miliseconds, and under repeats I changed from 1 to 0 in order to make it reapet until i press **Stop**.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Codeplex project - http://32feet.codeplex.com/ it allows you to open up Bluetooth sessions using C# through the native Windows stack. It will also allow a Bluetooth Serial Port (SPP) session which is what you'll want to use to connect to your device. The project is fairly longstanding and has a good amount of documentation on the site or on blogs if you Google.

Comment: I could not find full tutorial or example to use with Dev-Cpp, Code Composer Studio, or Visual Studio. All I need is to generate random 12 digit long int, and send it through the bluetooth.

Comment: I kinda found a workaround for what I needed. I found that RealTerm is able to send a line by line data from a txt file with delays between lines and the option to repeat the file over and over. So its kinda solved my problem.